# `git checkout <remote:branch>` results in mixture of files line endings "ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators"

Tags: git, macos, command-line-interface, bitbucket

I work on a cross-platform project (mainly Win and Mac users, and I'm on Mac) where source-code is stored in BitBucket.

It's been noticed for a while that occasionally my commits cause the line endings for everyone, resulting sometimes to merge conflicts.

### My git settings are:

- git version 2.36.1 from GNU installed via MacPort into `/opt/local/bin/git`
- `git config core.attributesfile` –> N/A
- `git config core.autocrlf` –> **input**
- `git config core.eol` –> **lf**

Trying to troubleshot, I get as closed as to this below:

### My workflow #1 (common) local –> BitBucket

1. `git checkout -B <work_branch>`
2. `file LiteCustomerSubscriptionMapper.java` –>
   `LiteCustomerSubscriptionMapper.java: Java source, ASCII textJava source, ASCII text`
3. edit in IDE, occasionally in vim or sublime, merging happens usually via Kaleidoscope
4. `git push --set-upstream origin <work_branch>` followed by
5. `git add "**/*.java";` `git commit -m "some message";` `git push`

After this, file remains with correct endings, no one complains.

However, when I do the second workflow

### Workflow #2 (prefered by others, at least on Win) Bitbucket –> local –> Bitbucket

then my line ends are screwed.

1. BitBucket –> create a work (merge_branch)
2. `git remote update; git pull --all; echo $?`
3. `git checkout <merge_branch>` will checkout the same files as above with different line endings!
4. `file LiteCustomerSubscriptionMapper.java` –>
   `LiteCustomerSubscriptionMapper.java: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators`
5. Editing that file in IDE will heal it.
   Performing the visual diff & merge in Kaleidoscope will sustain the damage.
   open the file in vim show how much it is screwed
   [image: mixed line endings in vim]
   Using `dos2unix` will heal it too, but I don't want to think about it and don't want to remember the subtle difference in the way how I checkout a branch.

So the question is:

### What needs to be done to have consistently files checkout locally with `LF` ending on Mac?

- Can I resolve it only by myself in some better way of configuring git locally (I mean on my local computer)?
- Do others, need to do something too with their git clients? (I'm probably only one in the Java team who is using CLI git. Rest of them Wins/Macs are using Eclipse to do their business).
- Does something need to be adjusted on the git server (BitBucket)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not clear in your question is what you (or your team) consider the correct line ending in BitBucket. Should it all be just LF, or do you want some with LF and some with CRLF? The best is to configure your editor to use the same line ending you want to Git, and set `core.autocrlf` to False, really.

Comment: If your colleagues working on Windows machines want CRLF's in your Git repo, then ideally you'll want to configure your Mac to respect that, which is really not a natural thing to do. This is an interesting question because it's usually the people on Windows that have and cause problem, and the people on Mac or Linux where things are all fine.

Comment: @joanis: in this case, I suspect it's that the Windows people are creating committed files that do have CRLF line endings (though perhaps only on specific lines). It's very hard to tell without direct access to the repository in question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should add a `.gitattributes` file to the repo reflecting the `text` attribute and then immediately run `git add --renormalize .` and commit.

The `text` attribute in `.gitattributes` tells Git that you want line-ending conversion done, and setting `text=auto` asks Git to guess which files are text and which are binary.  If you have files which must always have a given line ending to function (e.g., all shell scripts, regardless of platform, must use LF endings), then you can add the attribute `eol=lf` or `eol=crlf` as appropriate.

An example file might look like this:

```
* text=auto
*.sh text eol=lf
*.bat text eol=crlf
*jpg -text
```

Once you've done that, Git will use the user's preferred line endings in the working tree and store LF in the repository, which makes `git diff` work properly.  The Git FAQ [has an entry which discusses this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#recommended-storage-settings).